How do I stake ether on Holesky?
I've been collecting ether from Holesky faucet for about 40 days and counting, and no where to move it but a few layer 3 options that has no staking methods. Is there anyone who knows how to stake Holesky ether?

https://www.ankr.com/docs/liquid-staking/eth/stake/
